# Wordpress - UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, utf-8

I have a wordpress site where the header content is leaking into the body tag. I have read that this might be solved by changing to UTF-8 without BOM.

I am not sure how to know whether UTF-8 is with out without boom. My meta charset is set like this in the header.php of my template:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
```

The DOM result looks like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

**How do I know if UTF-8 is with or without BOM? And how can I change if if necessary?**

Comment: _UTF-8 without BOM_ is a format to save text documents in, especially your program sources. It is supported by most editors, like Sublime, Notepad++ etc.

Comment: set your editor to save your file 'without BOM' by default;

Comment: in case you don't understand syck answer, he is basically saying that the problem comes from the way you are saving your source files, not the way it is declared in the html

Comment: Ok, I see! Found the save without BOM option in sublime. Noob question: how can I determine if my files are already saved without BOM?

Comment: I think there is no standard way. But perhaps there are some tools out there which might do the job. Or you can write your own script which opens all files and checks the first three bytes (U+FEFF or bytes 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF). You can also remove those two bytes and overwrite the file in order to fix the files instead of only finding them.